# htaccess: Catch a specific URL type that contains a real subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a "something.php" and a subfolder in the root directory and there are html files in this subfolder. I want to catch a specific URL type that contains this subfolder.

```
.htaccess
something.php
/subfolder/1.html
/subfolder/2.html
/subfolder/image.jpg
...
```

So I want a RewriteRule like this (only for html):

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*).html$ /something.php?file=subfolder/$1.html [L]
```

In this moment the server try to open 1.html directly in subfolder and not with something.php What is the problem with my rule? Thank you for your help.

Comment: you would usually not have a `1.html` and rewrite access to it. you would rewrite to something.php which would decide aht to output

Comment: Possibly `mod_rewrite` is not enabled or `RewriteEngine` is `off`

Comment: @smith I have lot of (50+ htmls with unique name, number was just example)

Comment: @Arvind RewriteEngine and the other RewriteRules are working correctly.

Comment: @Halp paste the rest of .htaccess

Comment: @MohammedElhag Sorry but this is a working and complex htaccess with lot of sensitive data, I can't paste it. As I said, other RewriteRules are working good but I want to extend them with a new function.

Comment: @Halp the rule is working fine so , maybe there is prior rule that affect it before being applying , just look deep at your code , also ou could save htaccess file then test it